# How to convert a list of lists, each of which contains a single integer, to a list of integers?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists of integers like this:

```
x = [[1], [2], [3]]
```

How do I convert it to a list of integers:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
```

I was wondering if there are other ways to do it besides a for loop. Thanks!

Comment: See this: [How to make a flat list out of a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists).

Comment: Why don't you want to use a for loop?

Comment: @JohnGordon: see  "How to make a flat list out of a list of lists?" (https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/4906636) per Haveaniceday's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for using `.extend()` if you don't want to use a double for loop.

```
y = []
for small in x:
    y.extend(small)
```

But if a double for loop is fine for you then this could work too

```
y = [num for sub in x for num in sub]
```

output

```
[1, 2, 3]
```